# Multisite install with subdomains on a subdomain

Tags: multisite

I am building a website for a client.

It is going to be a multisite website. The test environment is on a subdomain of my own website. This url of this test environment forwards through an A record to other hosting

So:

- domein.com > server A
- sub1.domein.com > server B

On sub.domein.com (the main website of the client) I installed multisite wordpress. Now the trouble begins.

So the main website is “sub1”, that website works. Also the multisite installation went well. But now I want to add a new website, that is going to be sub2.sub2.domein.com. This is set up in this way, because when I am done and will move it to live sub1 will be the main domain. So then it wil be sub2.sub1.com

So I added a new website to the multisite installation “sub2".
I gave a DNS redirect like this:

- domein.com > server A
- sub1.domein.com > server B
- sub2.sub1.domein.com > server B

“Sub2” gives me a 404 when I click on “dashboard” in the wp-admin part (netwerk admin). The dashboard link goes to https://sub2.sub1.domein.com/wp-admin/
the “visite” link goes to the server but gives me a “Nginx is functioning normally”

How can I fix this? I am probably doing something stupid.
Please advice.

Comment: I don't believe this is caused by a WordPress problem, but instead it sounds like a Nginx configuration problem. WordPress might be configured to handle the sub-sub-domain but Nginx needs to know that `sub2.sub1` is also WordPress and to direct it to WordPress.

Comment: Ok, so I should ask my hostingprovider?

Comment: Yes, if you can't configure things so it knows that `sub2.sub1` is handled by your WP install, then your host can help. For reference, a blog on a multisite can have any domain you want, as long as the DNS points to its server, and the server knows to let WP handle it